# SQL Server 2016 CTP 2.2: Strong name validation failed error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2016 CTP 2.2 on Windows 10 Enterprise but I'm getting the error "Strong name validation failed"

Installation Pics: [Step 1](http://postimg.org/image/djw5vu9d9/), [Step 2](http://postimg.org/image/6opj1dyzj/)

I'll appreciate your help

Comment: almost certainly .NET 3.5 like here : http://serverfault.com/questions/546988/unable-to-install-sql-server-on-server-2012

Answer (score 1):

Might be missing .NET 3.5 SP1. Windows 10 does not enable .NET 3.5 by default so turn it on from Programs & Features then retry the install.